# Boolean method in groovy always returns true

Tags: dictionary, groovy, equals

This code is a little bit stupid but it represents the problem fully.
The two maps are different but true is allways returned. Why is this happening?

```
class SampleTest {

    private static boolean compare() {
        def a = [a:'one',b:'two']
        def b = [c:'three',d:'four']

        if(a.size()!=b.size()) {
            return false
        }
        a.each {
            if(!a.equals(b)){
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    static main(args) {
        println SampleTest.compare()
    }

}
```

If I add additional variable then all works fine:

```
class SampleTest {

    private static boolean compareArtifact() {
        boolean areEqual = true
        def a = [a:'one',b:'two']
        def b = [c:'three',d:'four']

        if(a.size()!=b.size()) {
            return false
        }
        a.each {
            if(!a.equals(b)){
                areEqual = false
            }
        }
        areEqual
    }
    static main(args) {
        println SampleTest.compareArtifact()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling return from inside a closure `each`

This will just exit the closure,  but will not return from the enclosing function

You can use `find` as an early terminating loop, and check the result for null

```
private static boolean compare() {
    def a = [a:'one',b:'two']
    def b = [c:'three',d:'four']

    if( a.size() != b.size() ) {
        return false
    }
    return a.find { a != b } == null
}
```

Or `return a == b` does the same as your compare method

Comment: Ok but How can I escape from the method(to return false) in the each closure? The above example is deliberately constructed and is only for showing pourposes. Can I say to Groovy to return statement not for corrent closure, but for the whole method?

Comment: @Xelian But what's your code supposed to return?  You compare `a` to `b`, but `a` will be a `MapEntry` and `b` will be a `Map` in your above example (so will never be `true`).  I've added an example of using `find` to my answer, hope that helps -- though it will still have the problem that it will never return `true`

Comment: Ok for __find__ but 'a' is Map and 'b' is a map too. I do not compare it in a.each, but the whole map a. SO if a.equals(b) true must be return. So to ask in another way if we are in closure like this how can we escape from this method and the rest of the method not to be executed. Like in java if we hit return the rest of the code is skiped? Can we do this in Groovy?

Comment: @Xelian You have 3 options. 1) Use something like `find` that stops when the closure returns `true` 2) Use an intermediate variable like your `areEqual` example 3) Use a for loop rather than a closure based looping structure.

Comment: @Xelian glad to help!  Sorry it took me so long to get to the point ;-) have fun!